# How to click this button with selenium for python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to click the "Vote" button using CSS selector, XPath, and classname. This is the URL I am visiting, https://birminghamhomeandgarden.com/fresh-kitchen-photo-contest-2023/#/rounds/1/gallery/372301007/.

My code

```
# Import the necessary modules
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

ser = Service(r"C:\Users\blah\Documents\Selenium\chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
driver.maximize_window()

# Set the URL we want to visit
url = "https://birminghamhomeandgarden.com/fresh-kitchen-photo-contest-2023/#/rounds/1/gallery/372301007/"
driver.get(url)
sleep(10)
votebtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until((EC.element_to_be_selected(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ember311']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button")))
votebtn.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues I found:

1. The main problem is that the BUTTON you are trying to click is in an IFRAME. In Selenium you need to switch the context into the IFRAME, do whatever you need to do, and then switch the context back to the main page once you're done.
2. Another issue is that you are using `EC.element_to_be_selected()` when you need to be using `EC.element_to_be_clickable()`
3. Using `sleep()` is not a good practice. Use `WebDriverWait` instead, as you already did. You don't need both... it just slows down your script.
4. A quick efficiency... if you are using Selenium 4.6+, it now has DriverManager which downloads, installs, sets up, etc. ChromeDriver for you so you don't need the separate driver manager and can remove all that code.

The updated code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

# Set the URL we want to visit
url = "https://birminghamhomeandgarden.com/fresh-kitchen-photo-contest-2023/#/rounds/1/gallery/372301007/"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='Promotion Embed']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ember311']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button"))).click()
```